# How to get mplayer to play from stdin?

Tags: linux, video, stdin, mplayer, tee

Why doesn't this work?

```
cat /dev/video1 | mplayer -
```

If I could get that to work, then I could play & record video at the same time using 'tee' to feed mplayer and mencoder.

I want to play live video (from /dev/video1:input=1:norm=NTSC) and record it at the same time without introducing lag.

mplayer plays the video fine (no noticeable lag).

mencoder records it fine.

But I can't figure out how to "tee" the output from /dev/video so that I can feed it to both at the same time. (I know ways to encode it, then immediately play the encoded video, but that introduces too much lag).

If mplayer and mencoder would read from stdin, then I could use 'tee' to solve this.

How can I do it?

[BTW, I'd be happy with ANY solution that plays & records at the same time, as long as it doesn't add lag - I'm not wedded to mplayer. But encoding first and then playing adds lag.]

Comment: Where's the the `/dev/video0` input coming from? A web camera?

Comment: /dev/video0 is the built-in webcam (it's a netbook).  /dev/video1 is the input I'm trying to read (a USB video adapter; it's connected to a receiver for a wireless camera)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8+ years later, I ought to post the solution I found.

Use Python. AFAICT, this isn't possible in with standard Linux tools alone.

If you're reading this - best to stop smashing your head against the wall.

Very roughly speaking - use pygame (import pygame) to read the camera and display the video, and OpenCV (import cv2) to save the video. This works.

Answer (score 11):

You need to give it some cache when playing from stdin

```
cat /dev/video1 | mplayer -cache 1024 -
```

Without that cache option you'll get the error
"Seek failed
Cannot seek backward in linear streams"

Comment: If you found this on some website could you add the reference to it here? Otherwise it's difficult to understand why this solves the OP's issue.

Comment: I compensated the downvote but only because you are a beginner here. Next time please give at least a minimal elaboration (references, explanation, anything), please.

Comment: I've edited in a clarification - mplayer needs the cache option in order to playback many streams from stdin.

Comment: This also solves the same problem ("Seek failed Cannot seek backward in linear streams") for http audio steams.

Answer (score 3):

According to the mplayer man page `mplayer -` should read from stdin, but you also need to specify `-noconsolecontrols` to prevent mplayer from trying to read keyboard control events from stdin.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to help - see here: http://pastebin.com/ai78v5W1 <br /> also, if I try it with /dev/video1 I get "Cannot seek backward in linear streams! Seek failed" (this is a _live_ video stream)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think what you want to do is possible using a single mplayer. I found this exact question asked and apparently answer thusly:

*excerpt :[[MPlayer-users] Display and record a camera ip stream at the same time ?](http://mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/mplayer-users/2010-August/080969.html)*

> > This work, but I really want to do it in the same mplayer process. Any
> >     idea how to write a stream in a file in slave mode ? I haven't find yet
> >     the right command in the documentation.
>
> I think it can't be done. MPlayer can play *or* dump a stream, not
>   both  at the same time.
>
> You can, however, dump a stream with one task, and play thar recording
>   stream with another task. At least you wouldn't have twice the network
>   traffic then.

The [original question](http://mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/mplayer-users/2010-August/080968.html) to that answer was this:

> I need, at the same time, to display the stream, and  the possibility to write it in a file (so, record it). My point is: I  would like to do this is the same process.
>
> Actually, I have a process for mplayer in slave mode:
>
> ```
>     $ mplayer -slave -wid id_window  camera_address/
> ```
>
> And each time I need to record, I start a new process, not in slave this  time:
>
> ```
>     $ mplayer -dumpvideo camera_address -dumpfile stream.mp4/
> ```
>
> This work, but I really want to do it in the same mplayer process. Any idea how to write a stream in a file in slave mode ? I haven't find yet  the right command in the documentation.

#### Using ffmpeg?

Just an idea but I found this wiki post on the ffmpeg website which discusses [creating multiple outputs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs). Perhaps you could split `/dev/video1` and then make use of the duplicate streams in mplayer?

Comment: I don't understand - that'll just play the stream, not record it.  I have no problem either playing or recording - I just can't do both at the same time.

Comment: @nerdfever.com - whoops I didn't realize you wanted to record it, let me update this.

Comment: Thanks; I know mplayer can't record and play at the same time. That's why I want to run 2 instances (one mplayer, one mencoder) at the same time, both reading from the same /dev/video1 device.  If I could get them both (mplayer & mencoder) to read from stdin, then I could use 'tee' to feed them both. But how to get them to take input from stdin in the first place??  [BTW, I'd be happy with ANY solution that plays & records at the same time, as long as it doesn't add lag.]

Comment: @nerdfever.com - added additional info about ffmpeg, let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll give it a try. I'm running Mint (Ubuntu) so I'll have to compile ffmpeg myself (they switched to avconv). If ffmpeg can do a video passthru (without encoding) then this might work - if it insists on encoding first, that'll add lag and it won't work for me... but I'll try it.

Comment: @nerdfever.com - you can download the prebuilt static builds of ffmpeg to save time, http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/.

Comment: I'm really struggling with this. I have ffmpeg installed, but I can't figure out even how to get ffmpeg to read from /dev/video1:input=1:norm=NTSC (it wants to default to input=0).  Then, once I can do that, how to pipe the output from ffmpeg into mplayer?  'ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 | mplayer -' complains that /dev/video0 is an 'invalid argument'.

Comment: @nerdfever.com - what about something like this? `ffmpeg -i input - | tee ...`?

Comment: Yes, what to put for "input"?  "/dev/video1:input=1:norm=NTSC" works OK for mplayer, but it's not the right syntax for ffmpeg. What is the right syntax?